# Is telling others how to crack software illegal?

Tags: software, germany

There's this program from a few years ago that isn't being sold anymore, and there's a simple way to extend the free trial forever by changing the expiration date in a text file.

I was wondering if it would be problematic to write and publish a guide on my website detailing how to use this exploit, since I am not distributing anything.

Comment: Is the program in question abandonware, i.e. the company behind it no longer exists, or is it simply not suported?

Comment: My location is Germany. And it's not abandoned, the company has moved on to a subscription based, in-browser model.

Comment: If the software isn't abandoned, then (a) you are trying to deliberately destroying someone's livelihood, and (b) nobody will lose a single tear if this costs you a lot of money. Germany has more laws than just copyright law.

Answer (score 4):

1. You are granted the free trial as part of a *trial*, not to permanently use the program.
   When the user downloaded the trial version of the program, he probably had to accept T&C granting a *one-time* *only* say 3‑month trial period.
   It is a mere **breach of contract** if you’re circumventing this, but you might still be liable to **damages**.
2. Circumventing technological protection measures is forbidden, [§ 95a UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0723).
   However, these protection measures must be considered *effective*.
   Now, lawyers are usually no computer gurus, so they might arrive at completely different conclusions, but I guess/hope editing a plain text file, substituting a plaintext ISO 8601 date, will not be deemed “effective”.
   (I presume the same effect could be achieved by resetting the computer’s RTC.)
   Having said that, since you intend to “publish a *guide* […] *detailing* how to use this exploit” I suspect it might not be that trivial and thus, from a lawyer’s POV, be considered an “effective” technological protection measure.
3. *If* it is considered an effective technological protection measure, you might be **punishable** via [§ 108b UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0866), but I’m not sure about that.
   The wording is terribly complex.